# Add-AzureAccount -credential not working as I'd hoped

Tags: powershell, azure

4 days ago (on 4th August 2014) there was a new release of Azure Powershell that included a new **-Credential** parameter on the Add-AzureAccount cmdlet. I'm trying to use it but I'm clearly doing something wrong.
First I store my password in a file:

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\temp\securestring.txt
```

Then try and use it in Add-AzureAccount

```
$password = cat C:\temp\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$username = "dhdom1\jamiet" #yes, this is the correct username
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$password
Add-AzureAccount -credential $mycred
```

The call to Add-AzureAccount fails:

> Add-AzureAccount : user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery
>   failed: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I know that "dhdom1\jamiet" is the correct account. Anyone any idea why this might be failing? TIA

Comment: Though am stuck with getting this locally working, curious to check how did you adapt the above for Automation runbook or function app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the organizational account you use to log in to the Azure Portal with.  So, it might look like jamiet@yourorganizationalaccountname.com, or something like that.

Comment: It's good to note that the -Credential parameter does NOT support Microsoft accounts at this time. It must be an organizational account.  If you don't have an organizational Active Directory linked to your Azure AD you can still create an Azure AD user, make it a co-admin and use that as well.  Every Azure subscription has an Azure AD by default.

Comment: I tried with my organizational account, but it gives me this error : Add-AzureAccount : Federated service at https://sso.organizationalaccountname.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed returned error: ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or 
authorized.: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

1. open azure powershell window
2. type Add-AzureAccount then enter
3. a login screen will be popuped to him then enter this credential outlook
4. by this, this credentials are stored in this PowerShell window, then run all other scripts from this specific window.